# What is the meaning of the confusing sentence?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1791528/synopsis)

> Shasta tells him about her new lover, Mickey Wolfmann, and asks Doc to
>   help prevent a plot by Mickey's wife and **her lover** to have Mickey
>   abducted and committed to an insane asylum.

if the word **her lover** refers to Mickey then why he himself want to have abducted and committed to an insane asylum.

that is why I am confused understanding this sentence.

What is the meaning of this above confusing sentence?

Comment: We would have to read the entire movie review to find out the answer! Can you tell us, please: Did an instructor or teacher tell you to read reviews at IMDB.com?

Comment: the wife's lover...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shasta tells [Doc] about her new lover, Mickey Wolfmann, and asks Doc to help prevent a plot by Mickey's wife and **her lover** to have Mickey abducted and committed to an insane asylum.

There are five people involved: Shasta, Doc, Mickey, Mickey's **wife** (who is *not* Shasta), and Mickey's **wife's lover** (who is *not* Mickey).

So it is Mickey's wife and Mickey's wife's lover who are plotting to abduct Mickey.